# Altium Trace, Silkscreen not solid ie only showing outline

Tags: altium, trace, silkscreen

Whilst working with Room Copy key command (D-M-C) I have inadvertently changed something which has resulted in my traces and overlays showing as their outline only.[image]

Does anyone know what I've done to change this back? I can't find any information related to this view (likely as I don't know what it is called).

Comment: I'm not at a place where I can check the exact wording, but in the layer/view dialog, go to the view options tab, and make sure all object types are set to "final" rather than "draft" or "hide". (I think what  you have is draft display)

Comment: Also, please say what version you're using. The exact way to get to this dialog is different in Altium 19 from earlier versions.

Comment: Yeah that's it. Thanks! AD18 in use. I had the view options tab selected to check/uncheck the room view and then by using D-M-C I have toggled D for draft view.

Comment: Great. Feel free to post an answer to your own question, now that you know how to solve the problem.

Comment: @ThePhoton perhaps since you offered the solution you should post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the outline of polygons or other objects in PCB view is Altium's "draft" setting in the **View Configuration** panel's **View Options** tab.

[image: Altium - View Configuration panel]

In Altium 19, there is a checkbox for each object type:

[image: Altium - View Options]